# PHP Not Able to Find File Even Though It Exists

Tags: php, file-permissions, directory-permissions

Everyone.

I am using an [image resizer script](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/) that resizes JPG images. It worked fine on *my* remote server but unfortunately it doesn't work on the client's server. :-|

The directories are writable (permission is set to 777). All I am getting is:

```
Error: image does not exist: /home/content/u/s/e/username/correct/path/to/existing/file.jpg
```

Here's the bit of the code that may be helpful in debugging:

```
// Images must be local files, so for convenience we strip the domain if it's there
$image          = preg_replace('/^(s?f|ht)tps?:\/\/[^\/]+/i', '', (string) $_GET['image']);
// ...
// Strip the possible trailing slash off the document root
$docRoot    = preg_replace('/\/$/', '', DOCUMENT_ROOT);
//...
if (!file_exists($docRoot . $image))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    echo 'Error: image does not exist: ' . $docRoot . $image;
    exit();
}
```

Please note that as a developer I have been given permission to access a subdirectory of the root directory.

I hope I made the problem case clear. I am at a loss as to what's going on behind the scene. Help is much apreciated

Comment: your `preg_replace` will fail for a simple http request (you have it matching only secure (s) protocols.  Not sure if that matter in this case.

Comment: @brombomb, thanks for pointing that out. I guess that's not the problem since it worked without any problem on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has to have access to all the directories leading up to the file, not just access to the file itself. If it doesn't have permissons on ALL of the directories, it's the equvialent of putting a "Free! take one!" pamphlet dispenser inside a vault inside Fort Knox - useless.

Comment: Does that mean that the root user needs to change permissions? If so, what should it be set to?

Comment: Possibly, depends on the ownership of the dirs. doing it as root just guarantees you'll be able to change the perms.